# Best Flags for Crash dumps

Tags: c++, crash

I currently have some code that will produce a crash dump when my application crashes however I can't work out what are the best flags to use for it are.

At the moment I have it using Full Memory (MiniDumpWithFullMemory) but this produces 32mg crash files. What flags should I use as to not make the crash file huge but give me the most power when coming to debug using it?

More info on the flags can be found at: http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always such a general answer.  The flags desired will depend somewhat on what you are trying to accomplish or for what you may be searching.

Perhaps you are having threading issues, MiniDumpWithThreadInfo or MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData would be appropriate.  If your program is corrupting its in-memory data, then MiniDumpWithFullMemory may be the choice.

From my own uses, having the full memory isn't always very useful -- I'll get what I need from the PEB or TEB structures, or just from the thread stack traces.

Also, look at the flags listed in a section of the site to which you linked: http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps2.html#strategies

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted an easy way to understand which flags i should use together

Answer (score 1):

Minidumps are highly compressible - I'd recommend zipping it to help out with the size

Comment: yes i do all ready but if the app is taking a gb of ram (for example) the full dump will take up a gb and compresses into 1/4 the size which is still 250mg (alot to upload to a server).